# SFML white rectangle

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to do a simple tile map. I have a problem: when I set up the map, there are only white squares. I'm normally loading the texture, so I don't know why it is like that.

Here is the code:

```
class Tile
{
private:
sf::Sprite sprite;
sf::Texture tex;

public:
     Tile(int x, int y, sf::Texture tex)
    {
this->tex = tex;
this->sprite.setTexture(this->tex);
this->sprite.setPosition(x, y);

    }
    void render(sf::RenderWindow* target)
    {
    target->draw(this->sprite);
    }


class Tilemap
{
private:
Tile tiles[36][64];
sf::Texture tex[4];

public:
//const/dest
Tilemap()
{
this->tex[0].loadFromFile("Resources/Tilemap/Water/water1.png");

int x = -WIDTH+WIDTH/2;
int y = -HEIGTH/2;
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
    {
        this->tiles[i][j] = Tile(x, y, this->tex[0]);
        x += 60;
    }
    y += 60;
    x = -WIDTH + WIDTH / 2;
}

}


render(sf::RenderWindow* target, sf::Vector2f pos)
{
for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
    {
        this->tiles[i][j].render(target);
    }
}
 };
 Tilemap map;
 map = Tilemap();
```

Comment: Did you check whether `loadFromFile` returned `true`?

Comment: @Botje ye i did

Comment: Then I don't see anything out of the ordinary. Please rework your question to an [mcve] so we can run it for ourselves.

Comment: @Bojte ok i will rework it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have dangling reference in `sprite`.

This dangling reference occurs in the below line:

```
this->tiles[i][j] = Tile(x, y, this->tex[0]);
```

What does [reference](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a3729c88d88ac38c19317c18e87242560) say about `Sprite::setTexture` ?

> The texture argument refers to a texture that must exist as long as
>   the sprite uses it. Indeed, the sprite doesn't store its own copy of
>   the texture, but rather keeps a pointer to the one that you passed to
>   this function. If the source texture is destroyed and the sprite tries
>   to use it, the behavior is undefined.

Where exactly is problem ?

```
Tile(x, y, this->tex[0]);
```

Here, new instance of `Tile` is created. `tex` and `sprite` are member variables of `Tile`. And `sprite` by `setTexture` is referring to `tex`.

```
tiles[i][j] = Tile(x,...);
```

In the above line, copy assignment operator is called which copies `sprite`/`tex` from temporary object - created by `Tile(x,y,..)`). As a result in `tiles[i][j]` you have `sprite` member which refers to texture of temporary instance - `Tile(..)` (`sprite` just holds pointer to texture). And finally, at the end of the full expression temporary instance is destroyed, `tex` of `Tile(..)` is deleted, and `tiles[i][j].sprite` holds invalid pointer to texture.

Solution?

You have to add copy constructor (copy assignment operator) of `Tile` to properly initialize `sprite` for holding its own `tex` (no reference to the instance the copy is made from):

For example:

```
 Tile& operator=(const Tile& theOther)
 {
      this->tex = theOther.tex;
      this->sprite.setTexture(this->tex);
      return *this;
 }
```

in default generated copy assignment operator `this->sprite` points to `theOther.tex` texture, which is wrong.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again and thank you for your answer but I don't know how can I implement it. I tried many options but none worked. If you will don't answer then it's okay, I'll try to somehow figure it myself. Thank you.

Comment: @Torsmel [Here is link](https://godbolt.org/z/JE7JrD) where I added copy ctor and copy assignment operator to `Tile` class. Check it and let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thank you so much but how can I concretely use it when I'm creating the map like above? I hope it doesn't bother you a lot.