# SFML compiles correctly, but I'm left with a white window when looping through my 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, sfml

I'm fairly new to SFML and somewhat experienced in C++. My game is a top-down shooter that has most of the game functions a top-down shooter would have, except for a map. I've tried using a tilemap with the VertexArray class, but I was pretty stuck when trying to detect collision between quads in the vertex array and my player. I then switched to a 2d array that has elements representing which sprite to draw. I have 3 std::vectors that contain my different tile sprites, and I loop through the array and push_back() a certain vector depending on the element in the array. When looping through the array and running the game, my window turns white with the loading cursor. Here is my code (Ignore the poor OOP. I really haven't used it that much):

```
class Tile {
public:
    int tileArray[4][4] = {
        {1, 2, 2, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1},
        {2, 2, 2, 2},
    };

    vector<Tile>sand, wall, wall3d;
    Texture sandTexture, wallTexture, wall3dTexture;
    Sprite sandSprite, wallSprite, wall3dSprite;

    void setUpTiles(Tile &tile) {
        sandTexture.loadFromFile("HUD/Sand.png");
        wallTexture.loadFromFile("HUD/Wall.png");
        wall3dTexture.loadFromFile("HUD/Wall3d.png");
        sandSprite.setTexture(sandTexture);
        wallSprite.setTexture(wallTexture);
        wall3dSprite.setTexture(wall3dTexture);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (tileArray[i][j] == 0) {
                    sand.push_back(Tile(tile));
                    sandSprite.setPosition(Vector2f(i * 32.f, j * 32.f));
                }
                else if (tileArray[i][j] == 1) {
                    wall.push_back(Tile(tile));
                    wallSprite.setPosition(Vector2f(i * 32.f, j * 32.f));
                }
                else if (tileArray[i][j] == 2) {
                    wall3d.push_back(Tile(tile));
                    wall3dSprite.setPosition(Vector2f(i * 32.f, j * 32.f));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void drawTiles(RenderWindow &window) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sand.size(); i++) {
            window.draw(sand[i].sandSprite);
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < wall.size(); i++) {
            window.draw(wall[i].wallSprite);
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < wall3d.size(); i++) {
            window.draw(wall3d[i].wall3dSprite);
        }

    }
};
```

when I start debugging, it finishes successfully, but I'm left with a white window that is constantly loading. However, when I comment out the two else-ifs in the setUpTiles function, the render window shows but only draws the sand vector. I want to be able to render all of the vectors and I'm unsure why this code doesn't work as intended. Here is the code that works:

```
class Tile {
public:
   int tileArray[4][4] = {
       {1, 2, 2, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 1},
       {2, 2, 2, 2},
   };

   vector<Tile>sand, wall, wall3d;
   Texture sandTexture, wallTexture, wall3dTexture;
   Sprite sandSprite, wallSprite, wall3dSprite;

   void setUpTiles(Tile &tile) {
       sandTexture.loadFromFile("HUD/Sand.png");
       wallTexture.loadFromFile("HUD/Wall.png");
       wall3dTexture.loadFromFile("HUD/Wall3d.png");
       sandSprite.setTexture(sandTexture);
       wallSprite.setTexture(wallTexture);
       wall3dSprite.setTexture(wall3dTexture);

       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
               if (tileArray[i][j] == 0) {
                   sand.push_back(Tile(tile));
                   sandSprite.setPosition(Vector2f(i * 32.f, j * 32.f));
               }
               /*else if (tileArray[i][j] == 1) {
                   wall.push_back(Tile(tile));
                   wallSprite.setPosition(Vector2f(i * 32.f, j * 32.f));
               }
               else if (tileArray[i][j] == 2) {
                   wall3d.push_back(Tile(tile));
                   wall3dSprite.setPosition(Vector2f(i * 32.f, j * 32.f));
               }*/
           }
       }
   }

void drawTiles(RenderWindow &window) {
       for (size_t i = 0; i < sand.size(); i++) {
           window.draw(sand[i].sandSprite);
       }

       for (size_t i = 0; i < wall.size(); i++) {
           window.draw(wall[i].wallSprite);
       }

       for (size_t i = 0; i < wall3d.size(); i++) {
           window.draw(wall3d[i].wall3dSprite);
       }

   }
};
```

I've been trying to make a map with collision for a few days, and I really want this option to work. I appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Google *SFML white square problem*. https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php, your problem is with Tile class, which is copied when calling `push_back(Tile(...))`. Sprite makes shallow copy of texture - it stores only pointer to texture which is dangled. Provide deep copy constructor/assignment operator for `Tile`, or use smart pointers to store your tiles instances.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631899/sfml-white-rectangle/59632612#59632612) is my answer explaining it in more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn’t know about that wow. I’ll try to implement it later, but I’m pretty busy right now. Thanks!